# Counting multiples columns and list the counts in separate columns and retain a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, count, range

I have the following Dataframe:

```
    id  coord_id    val1    val2    record  val3
0   snp chr15_1-1000    1.0 0.9 xx12    2
1   snv chr15_1-1000    1.0 0.7 yy12    -4
2   ins chr15_1-1000    0.01    0.7 jj12    -4
3   ins chr15_1-1000    1.0 1.5 zzy1    -5
4   ins chr15_1-1000    1.0 1.5 zzy1    -5
5   del chr10_2000-4000 0.1 1.2 j112    12
6   del chr10_2000-4000 0.4 1.1 jh12    15
```

I am trying to count the number of times each coord_id appears by each id but keeping the val1 column in the resulting table but only to include a range of the value in that column so for instance, I am trying accomplish the following result:

```
  id            snp    snv         ins    del   total val1  
chr15_1-1000    1       1           3      0     5     0.01-1.0
chr10_2000-4000 0       0           0      2     2    0.1-0.4
```

I want to sort it in ascending order by the column total.

So much appreciate it in advance.

Comment: I think you have made a typo, the value of total for `chr15_1-1000 ` should be `5`.

Comment: You are right, corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First pivot into `id` columns with count aggregation and margin sums. Then `join()` with the `val1` min-max strings:

```py
(df.pivot_table(index='coord_id', columns='id', values='val1',
                aggfunc='count', fill_value=0,
                margins=True, margins_name='total')
   .join(df.groupby('coord_id').val1.agg(lambda x: f'{x.min()}-{x.max()}'))
   .sort_values('total', ascending=False)
   .drop('total'))

#                  del  ins  snp  snv  total      val1
# coord_id                                            
# chr15_1-1000       0    3    1    1      5  0.01-1.0
# chr10_2000-4000    2    0    0    0      2   0.1-0.4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I got the following error when I ran the second step, it says AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute val1

Comment: You don't need to select columns before using `pivot_table`, it will take care of that also you can also pass `fill_value` parameter in the `pivot_table` itself. BTW congrats for reaching 10K :)

Comment: @aBiologist see if the update works better. it's combined into one step now

Comment: @ShubhamSharma thank you! updated the pivot, and appreciate the congrats!

Comment: Still, I got KeyError: 'val1'

Comment: @aBiologist Check the output of `df.columns` and make sure the column `val1` exists. If `val1` exists and still you are getting the error you could try `df.groupby('coord_id')['val1']` instead of `df.groupby('coord_id').val1`

Comment: The error is gone but I don't understand why the columns are not doing any counting, they all end up with decimal points values filling.

Comment: @aBiologist with the latest edit, the code should result in all integer counts now

Comment: You made my day, I was so depressed not be able to get the answer. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making two computations separately -- get the range and count the frequency.

```
temp = test_df.groupby(['coord_id']).agg({'val1': ['min', 'max']})
temp.columns = temp.columns.get_level_values(1)
temp['val1'] = temp['min'].astype(str) + '-' + temp['max'].astype(str)
```

Then,

```
temp2 = test_df.groupby(['coord_id', 'id']).count().unstack('id').fillna(0)
temp2.columns = temp2.columns.get_level_values(1)
```

And, finally, merging

```
answer = pd.concat([temp, temp2], axis=1)
```